# Replace all header tags with h4 in java using Jsoup

Tags: java, html, jsoup

I have the following html :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<h2> heading here </h2>
<p>This is a paragraph.</p>
<p>This is another paragraph.</p>
<h3> heading here again </h3>
<p>This is another another paragraph.</p>
<h4> heading here again </h4>




</body>
</html>
```

How can I replace all the h tags with h4 tags using Jsoup? I don't wish to use regex for this.

Comment: JSoup's `Element` lets you [rename](https://jsoup.org/apidocs/org/jsoup/nodes/Element.html#tagName(java.lang.String)) the tag. Have you attempted anything yet?

Answer (score 2):

Damn, Didn't know about the replace functionality earlier in jsoup. Here's how easy it is:

```
Document examString111 = Jsoup.parse(examString);
Elements elements = examString111.select("h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6");
elements.tagName("h4");
```